# vertical align in inline-block list grid layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried to put vertical align middle in list (li tag) which has display inline-block.But images are not aligned middle.

When I tried to give same height "li" and inner section middle. Its not working.

My issue: 
[image]

My CSS:

```
.home_page_list .woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 24%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

My link: [Click here](https://www.timberpergolas.co.uk/)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself rather than linking to a site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, working with `flexbox` is the best choice.

Simply add this code to your CSS:

```
body .home_page_list .woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    display: -webkit-box; 
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

If you want to learn how `flexbox` works this is one of the best resources on the net: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Basically, `align-items` set to `center` will vertically center the children of the element you apply the styles.

Comment: thanks for answer. I have tried your css. but its not working.

Comment: @vrajesh actually it should work. I've tried it out. what if you just use `body .home_page_list .woocommerce ul.products li.product` as selector? I've updated the code

Comment: yes, its working in firefox. but its not working in safari

Comment: yes, Orlandster. I am really appreciate your answer. Its still not working in internet explorer 11. Is there any way to use inline-block or table property to make it align middle?

Comment: I've updated my answer with all the vendor prefixes. this should work in all common browsers. see here: https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex

Comment: Thanks @Orlandster , I appriciate your help, marked as right.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
     align-items: center
    justify-content: center
    margin: 0 auto
```

And if don't work, as mentioned above, try  to use flex and flex-direction